# Loop through 50,000+ rows and copy data until value in the first column changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet with 50,000+ rows of data from A:N. I have a Master Data Sheet that has a query in the BackupData worksheet. I currently copy that data and paste as values into the Backup worksheet. With the headers:

| ID | Vendor # | Name | Customer # | Customer | Invoice # | Date | Item# | Item Description | Qty | B/C | Lbs | Amt | Amt#2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I am trying to loop through all of these rows and copy the range of cells A:N until the first value change in Column A, the first different ID #.

I then need to paste the selected range into a new workbook.

Basically, I want to do the opposite of consolidating.

```vb
Sub inserting()
    Dim wsBData, wsExport, wsCoverSht, wsBackup As Worksheet
    Dim wbAllRebates, wbSingle As Workbook
    Set wbAllRebates = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsBData = wbAllRebates.Sheets("BackupData")
    Set wsBackup = wbAllRebates.Sheets("Backup")
    Dim rID, rTopRow As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Counter As Integer
    i = 3
    Set rTopRow = Rows(1)
    Set rID = wsBackup.Range("A1")
    
    wsBData.Cells.Copy
    wsBackup.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    Counter = 0
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Do
        If rID.Offset(i).Value <> rID.Offset(i - 1).Value Then
            Rows(rID.Offset(i).Row).Insert shift:=xlDown
            Call SubTotals(rID.Offset(i), rTopRow)
            i = i + 1
            Set rTopRow = Rows(rID.Offset(i).Row)    
        End If
    Exit Do
    Loop
    
    MsgBox i
    
End Sub
    
Sub SubTotals(rID As Range, firstRow As Range)
    rID.Value = "Total"
    rID.Offset(, 9).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(firstRow.Cells(1, 10).Address & ":" & rID.Offset(-1, 1).Address))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SeparateWB()

    Dim wsBData As Worksheet, wsBackup As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim wbAllRebates As Workbook, rngHeader As Range
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, LastRow As Long, StartRow As Long
       
    Set wbAllRebates = ActiveWorkbook
    With wbAllRebates
        Set wsBData = .Sheets("BackupData")
        Set wsBackup = .Sheets("Backup")
    End With
    
    wsBData.Cells.Copy
    wsBackup.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    StartRow = 2
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With wsBackup
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngHeader = .Range("A1:N1")
        For i = 2 To LastRow
           ' change ID next row
           If .Cells(i, "A") <> .Cells(i + 1, "A") Then
               ' create new workbook
               Set wb = Workbooks.Add(1)
               rngHeader.Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
               .Range("A" & StartRow & ":N" & i).Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A2")
               wb.SaveAs .Cells(i, "A") & ".xlsx"
               wb.Close False
               ' move to next
               StartRow = i + 1
               n = n + 1
           End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox n & " workbooks created"
End Sub
```